# Get rid of POST/redirect/GET pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

I noticed that whenever I do POST request and redirect in Spring, it is redirected to GET request. Is there any setting to turn this behavior off? I would like POST be redirected to POST.

I need it for two reasons:

1. We serve application over http and https. Http is redirected to https with a connector:

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setSecure(false);
        ...
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        ...
        connector.setRedirectPort(httpsPort);
        return connector;
    }
```

Everything is fine with online authentication. User comes over HTTP, is redirected to HTTPS, login page is displayed. Authentication goes over HTTPS.

Problems occur with API authentication. I need a way to authenticate users directly from url. For example: [POST] http://myapp/api
Credential information are passed in request body. This request is redirected to HTTPS, but body is lost. Do you think that enabling HTTP in this case is insecure and we should resign from it?

2. We have a lot of legacy code, where frontend is built on one url - additional parameters specify which handler should handle given request. To avoid rewriting frontend we have a forward that sends requests to respective urls.

```
return new ModelAndView("forward:/" + action + "?" + extraParams + bodyParams);
```

This works, however I can imagine that in some cases body will be too large to be passed over GET in a url.

Technology:
Spring boot: 2.0.6

Comment: Can you comment on _why_ you would want this? From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get: "Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a web development design pattern that prevents some duplicate form submissions, creating a more intuitive interface for user agents (users). PRG supports bookmarks and the refresh button in a predictable way that does not create duplicate form submissions."

Comment: Sure. I've added the explanation in question.